# SwiftUI How to create a questionnary with result personalised?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I want create a questionnare with personnalized results. My biggest problem is the `Done` button.

Example: someone chooses : Destination: USA, 2 adults 2 kids travelling, and have passport, and at the end `Done` button.

I know how to code the Button, but I don't know how to use this information from the user and then bring it into a new view for a summary.. Can someone let me know how I can do this?

```
class FormDATA: ObservableObject {
    
    @State var country = ["USA", "Japan", "Deutschland"]
    @Published var index = 0
    @Published var peopleAdult = 0
    @Published var peopleKids = 0
    @Published var passeport = false
    
}

struct ChoiceCountry: View {
    
    @StateObject var choiceForm = FormDATA()
    
    var body: some View {
            Section {
                Picker(selection: $choiceForm.index, label: Text("Choice Country")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< choiceForm.country.count) {
                        Text(choiceForm.country[$0]).tag($0)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NumberPeople: View {
    
    @StateObject var choiceForm = FormDATA()
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Stepper(value: $choiceForm.peopleAdult, in: 0...6) {
                Text("Number of adults traveling : \(choiceForm.peopleAdult)")
            }
            Stepper(value: $choiceForm.peopleKids, in: 0...6) {
                Text("Number of kids traveling : \(choiceForm.peopleKids)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Document: View {
    
    @StateObject var choiceForm = FormDATA()

    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Toggle(isOn: $choiceForm.passeport) {
                Text("Did you have a passport?")
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possible ways to accomplish this, depending on your needs. Here's one:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject var choiceForm = FormDATA()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ChoiceCountry(choiceForm: choiceForm)
                NumberPeople(choiceForm: choiceForm)
                Document(choiceForm: choiceForm)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Summary(choiceForm: choiceForm)) {
                        Text("Done")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct ChoiceCountry: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var choiceForm : FormDATA
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Picker(selection: $choiceForm.index, label: Text("Choice Country")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< choiceForm.country.count) {
                    Text(choiceForm.country[$0]).tag($0)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NumberPeople: View {
    @ObservedObject var choiceForm : FormDATA
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Stepper(value: $choiceForm.peopleAdult, in: 0...6) {
                Text("Number of adults traveling : \(choiceForm.peopleAdult)")
            }
            Stepper(value: $choiceForm.peopleKids, in: 0...6) {
                Text("Number of kids traveling : \(choiceForm.peopleKids)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Document: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var choiceForm : FormDATA
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Toggle(isOn: $choiceForm.passport) {
                Text("Did you have a passport?")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Summary : View {
    @ObservedObject var choiceForm : FormDATA

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Country: \(choiceForm.country[choiceForm.index])")
            Text("Passport? \(choiceForm.passport ? "true" : "false")")
            Text("Num adults: \(choiceForm.peopleAdult)")
            Text("Num kids: \(choiceForm.peopleKids)")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's another, with everything on different pages.

```
class FormDATA: ObservableObject {
    let country = ["USA", "Japan", "Deutschland"]
    @Published var index = 0
    @Published var peopleAdult = 0
    @Published var peopleKids = 0
    @Published var passport = false
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject var choiceForm = FormDATA()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ChoiceCountry(choiceForm: choiceForm)
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct ChoiceCountry: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var choiceForm : FormDATA
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $choiceForm.index, label: Text("Choice Country")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< choiceForm.country.count) {
                    Text(choiceForm.country[$0]).tag($0)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
            
            NavigationLink(destination: NumberPeople(choiceForm: choiceForm)) {
                Text("Next")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NumberPeople: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var choiceForm : FormDATA
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper(value: $choiceForm.peopleAdult, in: 0...6) {
                Text("Number of adults traveling : \(choiceForm.peopleAdult)")
            }
            Stepper(value: $choiceForm.peopleKids, in: 0...6) {
                Text("Number of kids traveling : \(choiceForm.peopleKids)")
            }
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Document(choiceForm: choiceForm)) {
                Text("Next")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Document: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var choiceForm : FormDATA
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Toggle(isOn: $choiceForm.passport) {
                Text("Did you have a passport?")
            }
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Summary(choiceForm: choiceForm)) {
                Text("Done")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Summary : View {
    @ObservedObject var choiceForm : FormDATA

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Country: \(choiceForm.country[choiceForm.index])")
            Text("Passport? \(choiceForm.passport ? "true" : "false")")
            Text("Num adults: \(choiceForm.peopleAdult)")
            Text("Num kids: \(choiceForm.peopleKids)")
        }
    }
}
```

In either solution, a common `FormDATA` is shared between all of the views. The `Done` button is a navigation link that brings the user to the next page.

Comment: I use the first code, I train with, it's already more understandable for me, thank you very much